# RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualhost

I got a legacy project based on Django as backend and Angularjs on the front. It's deployed and working, but I got no docs at all so I had to guess everything out of how to deploy it in local, how the system works and that.

Now, I've been asked to set it up in a pre-production environment, and so I tried to do, I copied all the configs from the production server and changed as necessary to fit the new environment

```
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612256 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429] mod_wsgi (pid=13884): Target WSGI script '/opt/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612336 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429] mod_wsgi (pid=13884): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612539 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612602 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429]   File "/opt/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612611 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612624 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612632 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612643 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612649 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612659 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 81, in populate
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612666 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Thu Mar 15 07:08:53.612693 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13884:tid 140222719059712] [remote 212.170.177.164:49429] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

I tried to access that file (registry.py) and edit it so I could see what's going on inside, but it doesn't print anything on the Django console, neither in a file.

Here are my config files:

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.my_domain.com.conf

```
WSGIPythonPath /opt/mysite:/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:80>
        WSGIScriptAlias /backend /opt/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

        <Directory /opt/mysite/mysite/>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/opt/mysite:/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup mysite

        Alias /media/ /opt/mysite/media/
        Alias /static/ /opt/mysite/static/

        <Directory /opt/mysite/media>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /opt/mysite/static>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>


    ServerName dev.my_domain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@my_domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev.my_domain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/virtual.host.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/virtual.host.access.log combined
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/html/dev.mydomain.com/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css¦js|html|png)

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html
```

The Django server can be run properly from the console without any error but the requests never reach it.

I'm running Python3.6 and Django 1.9.5 (same as the prod server) over Ubuntu 17.04. The .htaccess has been copied from the prod server as it is. The firewall is not blocking the port 8000 for Django. Not running over virtualenvs

Any suggestions of how to face this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error out of a simple `$ python manage.py shell` in my case. I couldn't find any help out of searching for *RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")*, so I finally set about poking through it in the debugger.

In my case, it turned out to be that Oracle wasn't happy over my environment variables.

If that's not your problem, 'cause you checked that, then here are some steps that might help.

## Summary

I had to get to the right point in the code where the following happens. This is before the point where it blows up completely, so unfortunately you can't just run the debugger to the final point and hit `[w]here` to see the trace:

    `(Pdb) n
    ImproperlyConfigured: Improper...ectory',) <<- that's it, folks`

To display what that cryptic abbreviated message is, the `[w]here` command reveals (at the end of the stack):

    `(Pdb) w
    [...]
    -> raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading cx_Oracle module: %s" % e)
    (Pdb)`

So it turns out that I forgot to load a few environment variables and Oracle failed to load. *Sigh.*

## Detail

If you decide to use this method, I recommend setting your breakpoint like this (your line number may vary - versions change):

- Run the app in the debugger, and let it fail.

  ```
  (env) [prompt] $ python -m pdb manage.py shell 
  > <fullpath>/manage.py(2)<module>()
  -> import os
  (Pdb) c
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    [snip]
    File "<path>/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
      apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "<path>/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
      raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
  RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
  Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
  Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program 
  > <path>/django/apps/registry.py(78)populate()
  -> raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
  (Pdb)
  ```
- Take note of the fact that it failed (in my case) in registry.py. Look around in registry.py while you're here. You're looking for the line where it calls the `import_models()` method. In my case, line 104 gets me in the neighborhood:

  ```
  (Pdb) l 104
   99                 if duplicates:
  100                     raise ImproperlyConfigured(
  101                         "Application names aren't unique, "
  102                         "duplicates: %s" % ", ".join(duplicates))
  103  
  104                 self.apps_ready = True
  105  
  106                 # Phase 2: import models modules.
  107                 for app_config in self.app_configs.values():
  108                     app_config.import_models()
  109  
  (Pdb) l
  110                 self.clear_cache()
  111  
  112                 self.models_ready = True
  113  
  114                 # Phase 3: run ready() methods of app configs.
  115                 for app_config in self.get_app_configs():
  116                     app_config.ready()
  117  
  118  ->             self.ready = True
  119  
  120         def check_apps_ready(self):
  (Pdb)
  ```

Note that the code you're looking for is at line 108 in my example. That's where you're going to set your breakpoint.

- Restart (pdb won't reinitialize everything with a simple `restart`, so quit out and restart):

  ```
  (Pdb) q
  [snip]
  $ python -m pdb manage.py shell # just like you did before
  ```
- Now set that breakpoint:

  ```
  b django/apps/registry.py:108
  Breakpoint 1 at <path>/django/apps/registry.py:108
  (Pdb)
  ```

Remember: your line number may be different. `[c]ontinue` to the breakpoint.

- Now comes the part that requires patience: hit `[n]ext` until you get something that looks, well, suspicious is the only word:

  ```
  (Pdb) n
  ImproperlyConfigured: Improper...ectory',)  <<-- yeah, that bit, there
  > <path>/django/apps/registry.py(108)populate()
  -> app_config.import_models()
  ```
- **Now** is the time to hit `[w]here` in the debugger:

  ```
  (Pdb) w
  [snip the long traceback]
  [You'll see the line you're on now in the middle:]
  > <path>/django/apps/registry.py(108)populate()
  [snip]
  -> raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading cx_Oracle module: %s" % e)
  (Pdb)
  ```
- The `raise` line is what caused it to blow up.